# Replace exact matching word containing special character

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to replace a word in a string which contains same word with special character in it.

Example:

`string="this is a joke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke-club"`

I just want to replace the word joke with coke, not with the special character.

below command replaces all the word joke.

```
[chandu@mynode ~]$ echo $string | sed "s/joke/coke/g;"
this is a coke. this is a poor-coke. this is a coke-club
```

I tried using `sed "s/\<joke\>/coke/g;"`
but even this replaces all the words

Expected output:
`this is a coke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke-club`

Comment: Why do you use the `/g` flag if that's not what you want?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with special character. Could you give us an example which does not work as expected?

Comment: isn't dot `.` an special character?

Comment: above string is an example. My actual file is huge and contains the word "joke" multiple time. This is the reason why I have use `/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match beginning and ending of the word yourself if you want to include `-` as word character.

```
$ sed 's/\(^\|[^a-zA-Z-]\)joke\([^a-zA-Z-]\|$\)/\1coke\2/g' <<<"$string"
this is a coke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke-club
```

Answer (score 1):

Using perl and look-around to detect favorable leading (space) and trailing (space or period) characters around the word `joke`:

```
$ echo $string | perl -p -e 's/(?<=[ ])joke(?=[. ])/coke/g'
```

Output.

```
this is a coke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke-club
```

Comment: What about this string : `this is a joke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke` ?

Comment: @Philippe What's the expected output? If you are refering to the word `joke` in the end of the line, modify the character group for the positived look-ahead to `[. \n]`.

Comment: ... or to `(?=([. ]|$))`. That's probably better.

Comment: Yes, I was refering to the word joke in the end of the line, Reasonably, OP expects it to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in your case, the hyphen separates the string into different words.

i.e.: if I change your string to:

```
string='this is a joke. this is a poorjoke. this is a jokeclub'
```

and I'm running the command:

```
echo $string | sed 's/\bjoke\b/coke/g'
```

(where **\b** stands for: word boundary), I get the following result:

```
this is a coke. this is a poorjoke. this is a jokeclub
```

But when I'm applying this same command on your string, I get (as you do):

```
this is a coke. this is a poor-coke. this is a coke-club
```

So, in your particular case, I'd try something like:

```
echo $string | sed 's/\([^-]\)\(joke\)\([^-]\)/\1coke\3/g'
```

Which produces the following result:

```
this is a coke. this is a poor-joke. this is a joke-club
```